# Given the infinite series, justify carefully for which values of $p$ the series converges/diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series is \begin{equation}\sum^{\infty}_{n=5} \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^p}
\end{equation}

I tried using the Cauchy Condensation Test and ended up with \begin{equation}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{1}{(k \ln 2)^p}\end{equation}

From here, I am stuck. I wanted to get $k$ in the exponent so that I could view the second series as a geometric one. Please help!

Comment: Apply the condensation test one more time. You will get a geometric series.

Answer (score 6):

Just notice that $p$ is a constant, and so is $\ln 2$, so you can factor it out and your second series is
$$
\frac{1}{\ln^p 2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^p}
$$